# Mysql Update Query PHP Not working

Tags: php, mysql

i need your help.. i having a problem with mysql, when i run UPDATE query, the data wont updated..

here's the structure..

```
id_demand   | nama_item | hargajual | hargabeli | barcode   | part_number   | nosc  | stat_gudang   | stat_po   | stat_gudang2  | request   | terima    | id_po | id_pr | id_npb    | id_ttb    | tanggal_request   | tanggal_terima    | final_stat    | tipe
```

and here's the query...

```
$sqlx = "UPDATE item_demand SET stat_gudang = '1' AND id_pr = '$id_PR' WHERE id_npb = '2'";        
mysql_query($sqlx) or die(mysql_error());
```

I dont know why is my query doesnt work, can anybody help me?

Comment: The above query will throw an error message.  Please always quote the error message as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you didn't get any errors ? It probably means your where condition isn't verified then.

EDIT: I just saw your syntax was wrong. Your SET clauses must be separated by commas and not "AND". Thus :
    SET stat_gudang = '1', id_pr = '$id_PR'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including data for the primary key and all foreign key constraints in your update.

Answer (score 0):

you have used AND Bitween two field

stat_gudang = '1' AND id_pr = '$id_PR'

Change code

stat_gudang = '1', id_pr = '$id_PR'

```
$sqlx = "UPDATE item_demand SET stat_gudang = '1', id_pr = '$id_PR' WHERE id_npb = '2'";        
mysql_query($sqlx) or die(mysql_error());
```